# Cookie code working in FireFox and Explorer but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

The following cookie making code works in Firefox and Explorer but not in Chrome.

I have set up alerts to stop the script and verify that the new Date() object is being created as intended. All 3 browsers indicate that the new Date() is being created and that adding 10 minutes to the expiry is also being done as expected.

Flow: login page --> page

This is the login page's code for creating a cookie:

```
/*
    Event handler for verify button click.

    @param event is the event that triggered this function.
*/
function checkUser(event){

    // interesting note: even though the button isn't of type submit, it submits the form.
    // this prevents the form from being submitted:
    event.preventDefault();

    // obtain user name from form 
    var name = this.form.userName.value;

    // obtain password from form 
    var password = this.form.password.value;

    // is the password valid?
    if(isValidPassword(password)){

        // create new Date object for cookie's expiration
        var expires = new Date();

        if(expires){
            alert(expires.toString());
        }

        // increase expire time by 10 minutes
        expires.setMinutes(expires.getMinutes() + 10);

        alert(expires); // Firefox & Chrome show with additional 10 minutes.

        // write userName cookie
        document.cookie = "userName=" + encodeURIComponent(name) +
            "; expires=" + expires.toUTCString();

        // write password cookie
        document.cookie = "password=" +encodeURIComponent(password) +
            "; expires=" + expires.toUTCString();       

        // password is valid, allow entry to private web page.
        location.href = "project3.html";

    }else{
        // password was not valid
        alert("Password must be at least 1 character in length.");
        this.form.password.focus();         
    }
}
```

Then in the location.href "project3.html" this is the code that checks cookies. The alert(allCookies) pops up and shows the cookies in Firefox and Explorer but is completely blank in Chrome; **so I'm being immediately redirected back to the login page**. Which seems to indicate that either my cookie writing code is not working or cookies are turned off in Chrome? But I checked Chrome and the radio button for "allow local data to be set" under the cookies Content Settings is selected. So that leaves me thinking I've done something wrong with my cookie-making that Chrome doesn't enjoy, can you spot it and let me know what the issue is? Many thanks.

```
//
//  Ensure user has a right to visit this web page.
//

//attach load event listener to window  
window.addEventListener('load', verifyPassword, false);

// attach blur event listener to window
window.addEventListener('blur', verifyPassword, false);

/*
    Event handler for window load event. Ensures user has proper credentials
    via looking for password name:value pair held in document.cookie collection.
*/
function verifyPassword(){

    // decode cookies
    var allCookies = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);

    alert(allCookies); // Blank in Chrome; shows cookies in Firefox and Explorer.

    var password;

    // is the password cookie present?  
    if(hasCookie("password", allCookies)){

        // password cookie present, get password value 
        password = getCookie("password", allCookies);               

    }else{          
        // send user to login page 
        location.href = "project3_login.html";
    }

    // password is present, is it valid?
    if(isValidPassword(password)){
        // they get to stay     
        // cookie expires in...
    }else{
        // send user to login page 
        location.href = "project3_login.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem recently occured at my clients. Quite wierd, chrome developer tools shows that the cookie was set, but document.cookie does not shows it.

Answer (score 0):

i'm a newbie to javascript.  i studied cookies & broke my head on chrome.  my code works fine on IE.  but not on Chrome.  Chrome says cookies enabled.  but, i can't write one out.  Version 38.0.2125.111  if you go into "about" on chrome, you can get help.  apparently this is an issue.  chrome handles cookies in a different way.  i don't understand it.  i haven't studied it that much yet.  hope my pointer helps.